# How can I trigger mouse release event in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an element with draggable=true, would like to trigger once mouse is release with event mouseup. However it is not working.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div draggable=true @dragstart="dragStart" @mouseup="onmouseUp" name="dragdiv"><a href="#">Drag this</a></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default{
  methods: {
      onmouseUp: function(){
         console.log('mouse released')
      }
  },
}
```

Comment: What about `@dragend` as opposed to `@mouseup`?

Answer (score 0):

it has to be `@v-on:mouseup`. it doesn't work with `@mouseup`